# How can Javascript redirect a website user back to login page if need be?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, web

If a website user attempts to enter a secure page before entering the login page for the whole website, what script will be able to redirect him back to the login page without hindering his usage of the page normally (after he logged in)?

I am trying to do this with javascript and cookies. You guys have any ideas? Thanks ahead of time.

**I need the cookie creation and detection scripts. Thank you.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to handle this on the server-side. If you build this functionality with javascript, simply disabling javascript will allow the user to access your secured content.

Use a server side language for this.

Comment: I understand this, but the website is already encrypted by way of javascript (people cannot access it without code). I cannot use server-side-scripts. What i'm looking for is a redirection in the absence of a cookie.

Comment: @user2354952 It's encrypted with Javascript? What does that mean?

Comment: @user2354952 then you can't accomplish what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Is there any possibility he is using Node.js ?

Comment: I do not require redirection to the login page in order to block people from accessing the page. This is just an optional thing that I would like to add.

Comment: Please understand my question, and answer it if possible. I will worry about the logistics of it.

Comment: FYI, if you are curious, i am using [Protware web encryption] (http://www.protware.com).

Comment: Of course you can check if a cookie is present using `document.cookie` but trust me, if your secure content is only protected by client-side encryption there is no point.

Comment: Can you give me an example in another answer? Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2354952 I'm sure you don't care, as you only seem to want an answer to your question, but that thing is a joke. None of the things it guarantees works if Javascript is disabled (which can happen **after** a page is visited)...and can be manipulated with a browser console. I just did everything they say they "prevent" on their "encrypted" page.

Comment: `if (document.cookie.indexOf("cookiename") == -1){ // cookie is not present.}` by the way unless you are maintaining an old website and can't change it , i suggest you ditch protware. Trust me it is not securing anything. this made sense in 1997, they have document.all in their code...

Comment: But isn't it encrypting the html page itself? If someone loaded the page without javascript, they will just get a whole bunch of jibberish.

Comment: **Thanks ibu. Can I also get the code for cookie creation on the login page? I appreciate it.**

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. This solved it. Please post it as the answer to my question.

Comment: oops, maybe not. Can one of you give me the whole script from start to finish. (including cookie creation and recalling the cookie). Thanks.

Comment: you can follow the tutorial on the link i provided

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you must use server-side programming, or your website will become vulnerable.

And to avoid Cookie Hijacking you must use sessions.

php example:

**profile.php** -

```
if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) { $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"]; }
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) { header('Location: index.php'); }
```